# Android SQLite Search with OR , AND, in multiple database columns

Tags: android, sqlite, multiple-columns

I want to provide a query to my database that will search if a string exists in Column1 OR in Column2 AND only display it if another String value exists in Column3.

This my working code for searching in 2 columns :

```
mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                 KEY_TIME, KEY_TITLE, KEY_COLOR, KEY_BODY}, 
                 KEY_BODY + " like '%" + inputText + "%' OR " + KEY_TITLE + " like '%" + inputText + "%'" , null,
                 null, null, KEY_TIME + " DESC", null);
```

I cannot figure out how to add the third column to the Search though.

I tried this :

```
mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                     KEY_TIME, KEY_TITLE, KEY_COLOR, KEY_BODY}, 
                     KEY_BODY + " like '%" + inputText + "%' OR " + KEY_TITLE + " like '%" + inputText + "%' AND " + KEY_COLOR + "like '%" + colorvalue + "%'" , null,
                     null, null, KEY_TIME + " DESC", null);
```

but the AND only applies to the "TITLE" column not both. I've searched around the web but i couldn't figure it out.

Your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use brackets for this.

```
mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                 KEY_TIME, KEY_TITLE, KEY_COLOR, KEY_BODY}, 
                 "(" + KEY_BODY + " like '%" + inputText + "%' OR " + KEY_TITLE + " like '%" + inputText + "%') AND (" + KEY_COLOR + " like '%" + colorvalue + "%')" , null,
                 null, null, KEY_TIME + " DESC", null);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, but the brackets around KEY_COLOR are not essentials. Thanks

Comment: " + KEY_COLOR + " like '%" . A space was needed before "like".
Its working now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

> I want to provide a query to my database that will search if a string
>   exists in Column1 OR in Column2 AND only display it if another String
>   value exists in Column3.

So this shouldn't be too tricky. You need to add backets to your statement(for wraping first or condition) and then everything should work.

**Example:**

```
String query = "select * from SomeTable
                where (column1 like ? and column2 like ?) and column3 like ?";
String[] params = {"%" + param1 + "%", "%" + param2 + "%", "%" + param3 + "%"};
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, params);
```

Let me know.

**Note:** I really don't like your "harcoded" approach. I recommend you to use **parametrized statemets** which are **more human-readable** and **much more safer** than classic "hardcoded" statemets. Don't forget there is possible danger of `SQL` Injection.